# Slashes are not being displayed

Tags: php, string, php-5.4

This is my code:

```
<?php
      $lname = "templates/generator";
      $link = "<img src=\"{$lname}/data/num_{$row}.png\" alt=\"{$row}\"/>";
      echo $link;
?>
```

It does return this. Instead of an image, in the Firebug I can read the following:

```
<img src=" templates generator data num_1.png" alt="1">
```

So basically
 it is replacing the slashes with white spaces. **Where is the problem in this code?**

Comment: Add `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` to the top of your script. And try again.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña: Nope, you don't need to. The above should produce an output that's similar to `<img src="templates/generator/data/num_BAR.png" alt="BAR"/>`.

Comment: @AmalMurali Already have that.

Comment: \ are for escapeing your " so are never seen (php strips them internally). would be easier to not use then and just use single quotes around the outside of your string `$link = '<img src="{$lname}/data/num_{$row}.png" alt="{$row}"/>';`

Comment: And are you sure that's the output you're getting? Also, please post the `var_dump` output for `$lname` and `$row`.

Comment: Don't read this with Firebug - just ctrl+u and view the source code itself - Firebug may be having it's own issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better idea would be to stop using messing with your quotes. Just [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) for outputting the HTML:

```
$link = sprintf('<img src="%s/data/num_%s.png" alt="%s"/>', $lname, $row, $row);
```

Also, while looking at your source, use your browser's View-Source feature, and not Firebug. It may be having it's own issues, as Ben said in the comments.

And to make sure you're not misreading the information, you can use a neat little `header()` trick:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

PHP uses Content-Type `text/html` by default. Add this to the top of your script, and it'll display the HTML without any formatting and you can see what's really going on.

Comment: Interesting fact: When I do `var_dump($link);` the images are being displayed correctly in the var_dump output. When I use `echo 'Somethingsomething ' . $link . ' something';` nothing is being displayed but when I use the firebug on the output location I get the string I have given in the question.

Comment: @Lucas: Okay, delete everything, and copy the code from [this paste](http://pastie.org/pastes/8407956/text) and tell me what output you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Simply you should improve your line like this

$link = '<img src="{$lname}/data/num_{$row}.png" alt="{$row}" />';

Never use same commas in the same line, use different instead.
```

-

Thanks